# Unable to launch matlab

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, matlab, yum

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, I have succesfully installed matlab 2010b without any error. The same sofware had worked with Ubuntu 14.04, but with 16.04 it says:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libXp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also tried `yum` and `apt-get` to install `libxp.so.6` but it shoewd errors, which I have attached with screenshots.

[image: Error while lanching the matlab c]
[image: Error while installing libxp.so.6 using yum]

Running `yum repolist all`
tells "0" , which means there are no repositories, please help to add required repository to install `libxp.s0.6`

Comment: Any reason why you are using `yum` to install packages?

Answer (score 3):

That file is [not available anymore on Xenial](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=i386&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libXp.so.6) and other Ubuntu versions more recent than Trusty (also in Wily is not present).

Since Matlab is a proprietary software you should report the error to their developers, so that they can update the package and make it compatible with the new versions of Ubuntu and Debian.

In the meanwhile you can *probably* manually install an [old version for Trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=i386&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libXp.so.6), but probably it will also break other packages and dependencies in your system.

EDIT: The Matlab version that you are using is 2010b, so many things have changes since then. I strongly suggest that you use a recent version of the program (maybe 2016a, since we are here), in order to maintain compatibility with the systems you are using. In details, [that version R2010b supports officially only Ubuntu 9.10 and 10.04](http://it.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/files/SystemRequirements-Release2010b-ServicePack2_Linux.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

Try following solution

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

## append this line to sources list:

*deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main*

Then again on terminal run following commands

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libxp6
```

Source: http://shengweihou.com/wordpress/?p=232

Comment: Mixing different Ubuntu releases is asking for pain and a recipe for disaster. -1